Grease Pencil Line Art and Noise Modifier Flickering
I’m having an issue with the line art and noise modifier where the intersection lines are changing every frame instead of every 12 steps as set in the randomize section of the noise modifier tab.

The Modifier tab settings:

Is there a way to fix this flickering issue with the intersections?
I’m using Blender 4.2 Alpha with the new Eevee renderer. It shouldn’t matter but I might as well mention it.

Do you get the same flickering with no noise modifier ? Did you try increasing the stroke resolution (it would be Data > Strokes > Curve Resolution I think) ? Also, LineArt is somehow updating every frame (e.g. if camera is animated) so maybe this flickering is linked to this update property of LineArt.

@Lustzi The flickering stops If I disable is the noise modifier but I want the effect it gives to the silhouette. Increasing stroke resolution didn't fix anything. And nothing has any animation on it. Could it just be a bug with with the line art modifier?

I can reproduce your issue (4.1.0). I don't have any solution ... an half-solution is to Apply your Line Art modifier. Doesn't work if things move around, but you'll get rid of the flickering. Yes I think it's a bug/overlooked (no reason for line art to update if nothing moves).

Also, only Edge Type > Intersections appears to generate the flicker. Could you find a way not to use that kind of edge ? Maybe at the cost of merging multiple meshes of your character into one (I mean merging the topology of the meshes).

It's not really an artifact of the noise modifier, but rather the Line art modifier. The artifacts are more apparent because of the noise modifier, but it's because the underlying strokes change between each frame.
The Line art modifier is dependent on what the camera sees, if your mesh is not entirely comprised inside the view frustum of the camera, it will yield different results if you move your camera. One solution is to use a bigger render size so the entirety of your object is always comprised inside the camera view frustum, and crop the render result to your liking afterwards. One downside is it will take longer to render.


I just checked and it indeed doesn't fix the "Intersection" type lines which always seem to flicker.
